# How can I get the object which has been changed and also the new changed value when Selecting options from the drop down

Tags: reactjs

I have a react.js app that populates a table with a list of users, Each user on the table has a stage dropdown to toggle stages of users.
Problem is on the select `onChange` function I am trying to pass the object being changed and the new value being selected to a function.

how do I achieve this:

```
    <select value={user.stage} onChange={()=> this.onStageSelected(user)}>
        <option value="New">New</option>
        <option  value="contacted">Contacted</option>
        <option  value="Converted">Converted</option>
        <option value="Not Converted">Not Converted</option>
        <option  value="Archived">Archived</option>
   </select>

  onStageSelected =(user)=>{
     console.log(user)
  }
```

I have managed to pass the user being changed, but how can I get the new changed value, I need both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OnChange receives a callback to which the selection is passed:

```
onChange={(event)=> this.onStageSelected(user, event)}
```